# Update one branch from another

Tags: git, github, merge, version-control

In the 'old' GitHub for Desktop application there was a button that would allow you to update from another branch.

What this does, is takes any commits from the other branch that haven't been synced into the current branch and creates a commit for the merge.

The new desktop application is missing this feature, but I use it all the time. What is the Git command line version of this? What is the desktop application doing?

For a more detailed explanation, say I make three commits to master (or any branch). We'll call these commit A, B and C.

Then we branch from master (or any branch) and make a commit to the sub-branch. Let's call that D.

Then we make two commits to the original branch (commits E and F). How do I then replicate what the desktop application does and merge commits E and F into the sub-branch, creating another commit (commit G)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ git branch -l # just to show we're on develop branch and there's master branch as well
* develop
  master
$ git merge master
```

Will get `master` merged into `develop`.

Comment: And this will keep the master branch as it is? It won't modify the master branch?

Comment: It will only modify current branch. `develop` in my example. And it will not push anything to origin, so you'll have all the time in the world to checkout `master` and verify if it's changed or not. In fact you can copy your git repo to another folder, play with this new folder to your content and just delete that copy if you're really afraid to break something.

Comment: There is [this visual tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) of branching and merging in terminal.